# how to use mysql to handle get unique pairs and without reusing the elements in below table

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose we have a table below is regarding the devices scanning different packages. How to use MySQL(version8) to get each complete scan_package event duration. In order to consider a valid pair scan_package event duration, the action "start" should happen before the "end" action, and both actions should use the same device, and we only record the "start-end" **once**. (refer below table)

```
    CREATE TABLE record (
    device VARCHAR(100),
    eventTime datetime,
    event VARCHAR(100),
    actions VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO record VALUES 
( 'device1' , '2020-02-01 10:05:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device1' , '2020-02-01 10:10:25', 'scan_package' , 'start'),
( 'device1' , '2020-02-01 10:25:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device1' , '2020-02-01 10:30:25', 'scan_package' , 'start'),
( 'device1' , '2020-02-01 10:35:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device2' , '2020-02-01 10:40:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device2' , '2020-02-01 10:42:25', 'scan_package' , 'start'),
( 'device2' , '2020-02-01 10:47:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device2' , '2020-02-01 10:51:25', 'scan_package' , 'start'),
( 'device2' , '2020-02-01 10:53:25', 'scan_package' , 'end'),
( 'device3' , '2020-02-02 08:45:25', 'scan_package' , 'start');
```

the valid output should be something like below:

| device | eventTime1 | event | action1 | eventTime2 | action2 | scan_duration_in_mins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| device1 | 2020-02-01 10:10:25 | scan_package | start | 2020-02-01 10:25:25 | end | 15 |
| device1 | 2020-02-01 10:30:25 | scan_package | start | 2020-02-01 10:35:25 | end | 5 |
| device2 | 2020-02-01 10:42:25 | scan_package | start | 2020-02-01 10:47:25 | end | 5 |
| device2 | 2020-02-01 10:51:25 | scan_package | start | 2020-02-01 10:53:25 | end | 2 |

Based on the above table, we will begin with row2, since the first-row timestamp of end action comes before the start action.

Below is my code, however, it reuses the end action to the start actions of the duration calculation

```
SELECT 
*,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.eventTime, t2.eventTime) duration
FROM record AS t1
JOIN record AS t2
ON t1.device = t2.device
WHERE t1.actions = 'start' AND t2.actions = 'end'
AND 
t1.eventTime < t2.eventTime
```

Therefore, my code output had additional outputs due to resue the actions

Basically, the result should be a unique "start-end" pair, which we should not reuse the "start - end" corresponding timestamp.

Can someone please give me some suggestions or code?

Notes:

We can assume there is **no** below situation:

```
  device4  start 
  device4  start
  device4  start
  device4  end
  device4  end
  device4  end
```

Meanwhile, I am curious if we have the above case then how to handle it? (this could be a separate problem)

Comment: Do you have any possibility to add some 'action_id' which is unique for the corresponding 'start' and 'end' action? Otherwise you will get much trouble to find the correct start-end-pairs. Especially for your last "start-start-start-end-end-end" scenario. This would be not possible, nobody could say, which pairs belong to each other.

Comment: *Below is my code, however, it reuses the end action to the start actions of the duration calculation* Add a condition which ensures that there is no third row between those taken in current combined row (WHERE NOT EXISTS). But you use version 8+ - so use LAG() in CTE simply.

Comment: @Robert, I am also thinking of using row_number to add a ''index'' to track the pairs.

Comment: @Akina, I have attached my SQL details code below, if you could implement it there will be really helpful. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=368565fe3cb489887d94b32ff70424d9    thank you !

Comment: @Robert below is the link to my SQL code.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=368565fe3cb489887d94b32ff70424d9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for this problem:

1. add a unique key/index for each pair, so the filtering would be easy and clear. It would also be enough, if you add an extra column 'start_time', where you can insert the origin start time for each 'end' record.
2. add some extra knowledge. This means you have to improve your filter and get the "end" record with the *lowest* timestamp AND timestamp greater than the "start" record. Otherwise it depends on the DB, which record you will get (most likely the one, which was inserted first, but this is not guaranteed).

The second option requires a "correlated subquery", which is much slower.

I have updated your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12762f164b72a06849fd66d823d40ebe

This works good on small databases. But if you have much records, this can become really slow.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanations. And, I did verify your code which works. Meanwhile, I assume you used method 2 to do the questions. However, could you also please demonstrate method one?  Since I do believe the data will grow. Thank you again.

Comment: I think, the most simple would be, to add the 'startTime' to every 'end' action, if this is possible. This way, you can also show the duration for entries, where the 'start' action is missing (like in your example). If you don't want them, you could also filter them out pretty easy. Here is an example with 'startTime': https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a83f4365adbee44521d8aea22f416fe

Comment: thank you again for the updates. I kindly get the logic of your idea, is that mean we need to write some insertion SQL statement to the original 'record' table, which inserts all the 'start' actions times for each 'end' record. However, I did not see the insertion part and the correct output in above link. Maybe I did not fully understand your point.

Comment: I have just added a 'startTime' column, where I have added the corresponding start timestamp to each 'end' record. I don't know, if you have the possibility to do this for past records or just need it for inserting future records. Or do you need help to update the past records?

Comment: the only thing that I did not get is the link you provide, the new insert start time timestamp does not match the original 'record' table start time. And, if you can include the new insert statement will be great. thank you again.

Comment: As I can see, the 'startTime' matches the timestamp of the 'start' record at most records. In the example, there were two 'end' records with no corresponding 'start' record, so I've used fantasy timestamps as startTime (could also set to NULL, juts want to demonstrate, that you can get a duration from 'end' record only, even if the 'start' record is missing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243377/discussion-between-lawrence-and-robert).